# Log4Net : 2 libraries need 2 different version of it

Tags: .net, log4net, combres

For my ASP MVC website I need to use 2 libraries which both need a different version of Log4Net.

The first one which is a simple DLL, depends on version 1.2.10.0 and the other one installed using nuget package depends on 1.2.11.0.

There is no compatible version I could use and I need both of them, well speciable the dll the  other one is combres (I use to help compress and cache css and javascript). I couldn't find another libray to do same as combres but if you got one it could also be helpfull.

Thanks in adavance if you can help me out of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These people had the same problem and suggest two solutions:

http://www.andriybuday.com/2010/10/log4net-versions-deployment-issue.html

Comment: There were some helpfull tips, and it made me understant the issue a little better but still I found the source code (silly of me not not to do that at first) and I just updated the log4net library to work with my needs. But still thanks for your help